# Options other than JQuery for manipulating dynamic behaviour of .Net MVC form element

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to know is there any other possible ways in which we can manipulate behaviour of .net MVC form other that responding to JS events & updating attribute of of other form elements.

Comment: Are you looking for an alternative to Jquery or alternatives to Javascript in general?

Comment: I am looking for some sort of mechanism where I will update my model & form will respond to that